# Custom transition passing mapView

Tags: objective-c, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm looking for idea how to resize map to full screen when tapping on it. It came to my mind that custom view controller transition my do the job. Only problem is I don't know where exactly should I pass frame from first view and animate it on second? Can't find proper example of doing that.